# Overlaying text on image when hovering

Tags: html, image, text, overlay

Im trying to overlay some text onto an image on my page. I know that the code has to be in css but i can't get it to work without distorting and throwing everything off. Here is where the image is in my html code

```
<div id="current">
        <h3><u>Current Products</u></h3>
        <img id="nintendo" src="http://www.albany.edu/~jc191638/image/n641.jpg" alt="n64"/> 
        <span class="text">text text text...</span>
        <p id="nintext">
</div>
```

And here is the css for it

```
#current
{
    float:center:
    height:984px;
    width:600px;
    background-color:    #475F77;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    text-align:center;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:    #D74B4B;
}
#current:hover .text
{
    display: block
}
.text
{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width:100%
    background: #999;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    text-align: center
}
#nintendo
{
    height:70%;
    width:70%;
    padding-left:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If an item is position:absolute, then it is positioned relative to whatever the closest parent (that has position: relative or position: absolute) or relative to the body element if no parents meet that criteria.

So you have to add "position: relative;" to your containing div.

```
#current{
position: relative;
height:984px;
width:600px;
background-color:    #475F77;
padding-bottom:10px;
text-align:center;
border-style:solid;
border-color:    #D74B4B;
}
```

You can test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/PR3Vw/

Comment: This is closer to what I need, I actually only want the text to show up when I hover on the image, and for the text to be ON the image.

Comment: Then you would want to add the image and span element to a container div.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `float: center;` If you want to have text over image you can do it like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="holder">
  <img src="some.png" />
  <span id="over_img">This text is over image</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#holder {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* image is positioned to #holder top left */
#holder img {
  display: block;
}

#over_img {

  /* absolute positioning in holder */
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;

  /* image position property is static so image z-index = 0 we 
     just set this top of image by giving greater number for z-index */
  z-index: 10; 

  /* position relative to #holder top of image */
  top: 10px; 
  left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: is there not a way to put it in the css for the image? The div does not actually end there I simply left out the other things because I wanted the focus to be on the image.

Comment: sorry don't get what you mean.. css.. what put where?

Comment: No, but just add another div. Put "holder" inside of your "current".